# Packages Updater and Ubuntu Software Center don't work in Ubuntu Studio 19.04 upgrading

Tags: package-management, upgrade, software-center

I upgraded one of my desktop PCs from Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 to 19.04.

Now, the Packages Updater (GUI) and the Ubuntu Software Center don't work!

Both apps start to run but... They are indicating that something are doing, but... It seems to wait forever I don't know what!

I've been waiting for up 30 minutes, and... Nothing!

If I used a Terminal session and the commands:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

Everything is fine! No error messages at all!

So... What's wrong here?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of the following terminal command: `sudo apt update`

Comment: Nothing to add! The "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" commands are working so fine! No errors messages from them. There is something related with the GUI apps, only.